# TYPO3 12 News backlink to list view section

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-extensions, tx-news

I'm currently running TYPO3 12 on my one page website, which includes a news section. To get to the news section you have to scroll down a bit. This is fine so far. The problem is with the backlink in the detail view. As it stands currently, whenever you go to the detail view of a news article and use the backlink, you have to scroll back down to the news section.

Please note that this OnePager has all sections on a single page in the backend. So there's only the page "Home" which contains all sections like "Hero image", "News", "Contact" and so on.

So I would like to add the correct anchor link to my backlink, so that you don't have to scroll back down. To get the correct anchor link, I need to have the cObjectUid of the list view. How would I go about passing the cObjectUid from the list view to the detail view?

Here's a small illustration. The red arrow shows how the backlink currently behaves, and the green arrow how I want it to be.
[image]

I've tried adding a few additional arguments to the link and passing them on in the controller, but so far no success.

Here's my current code for the link, linking to the detail view:

```html
<n:link newsItem="{newsItem}" settings="{settings}" title="{newsItem.title}">
    Some text
</n:link>
```

And here's my current code for the backlink:

```html
<f:link.page pageUid="{settings.backPid}">
    Sometext
</f:link.page>
```

Edited for clarity

Comment: `f:link.page`-VH has a `section` attribute. Provided your list view has a section/ID, you should be able to link directly to the location.
https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/12.4/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Link/Page.html#section

Comment: That is correct, but I'm still missing the corresponding ID, which is the `cObjectUid` of the list view. I need to somehow pass this to the detail view so I can use the `section` attribute.

Comment: That depends on how you build the OnePager. A not uncommon approach is to write the page IDs (prefixed) as IDs in the HTML. This would make the backlink possible via `<f:link.page pageUid="{settings.backPid}" section="yourPrefix{settings.backPid}">`, for example.

Comment: I don't think this would work for a OnePager. Say the page ID is **1** and the prefix is **c**. If there's only one element on the page, this is fine. But what if there's more than one? Every element would recieve the same HTML ID, since they're all on the same page.

Comment: OnePagers that are managed via TYPO3 are always assembled from *several* pages, i.e. each section comes from one page. So each section can have an ID based on the page ID. Or do you want to jump from *different* sections to the detail view and then back to the correct section? Then perhaps one way would be to have multiple detail pages, each linking back to the "correct" list view/page.
I increasingly think you should reveal a bit more about the structure of your one-pager. Otherwise it's a lot of guesswork...

Comment: You're right, I forgot about that since I don't usually work with OnePagers. In the case of this OnePager, all the sections are on a single page, so that's why your suggestion with the page ID doesn't work in this case. I've updated my Question accordingly. I hope this clears things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

So I've figured out a way to solve my problem, but in my opinion it's not ideal, which is why I won't mark this as solved just yet.

I adjusted the detail view link and added the cObjectUid as an additional parameter to the URL:

```html
<n:link newsItem="{newsItem}" settings="{settings}" configuration="{additionalParams:'&tx_news_pi1[listUid]={uid}'}" title="{newsItem.title}">
    Sometext
</n:link>
```

Inside the Controller I can now grab that argument and assign it to the detail view.

```php
$additionalArguments = $this->request->getArguments();
$listUid = $additionalArguments['listUid'];
$assignValues['listUid'] = $listUid;

if (count($assignValues) > 0) {
    $this->view->assignMultiple($assignValues);
}
```

With this I can assign the correct HTML ID to the backlink.

However, there are still two problems with this:

1. If the URL doesn't contain the additional arguments, the backlink will no longer link to the correct section.
2. The URL doesn't look all that nice.

Comment: Perhaps several news detail pages could help, so that each list view has its own detail page. This would allow the detail/list page to be linked in the plugins. The disadvantage here could be that a news item could have *several* URLs for its detail view. It depends on your use case whether this would be a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I think you've misunderstood my problem. There's only one list view and one detail view. The problem lies with the backlink. It should link to the ID of the list view section. This ID contains the UID of the list view element, which I need to pass to the detail view. I've added a small illustration to my question that should hopefully clear

Comment: If there is only *one* list view in your OnePager, then you can hard-code the section/ID as an attribute in the news-detail template. Why then the desire for all this dynamism?